connecting to on-premise ldap server using the cloud connector
Im trying to connect to on-premise LDAP server from Cloud Foundry java application.
to my knowledge the connection require to go through the cloud connector as the proxy with jwt token.
using the Destination Service, CF has an LDAP type that should handle such connections. from some reason i cant make it to work.
does any one have a working java base application the made it work on CF?
thanks in advance.

